# Mongoose issue with AND OR query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to 'translate' a SQL query to Mongoose, but it fails to return any results.
Here's the SQL one:

```
WHERE (( a = 1 AND b = 1) OR ( c = 1 AND d = 1)) AND (date = '2018-03-20')
```

**Here the mongo query version:**

```
$and: [
            { $or: [ {$and: [{searchCode: 123},
                             {searchNumber: 987} 
                            ]
                     },
                    {$and:  [{Code: 123}, 
                             {Number: 987}
                            ]
                    }
                ]                            
            },
            {date: '2018-03-20'}
        ]
```

There are values in the database which should be returned, but the query fails to return results.

Please advise.

Comment: You do not need an explicit [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{
    date: valueDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    $or: [{
        searchCode: newCode,
        searchNumber: newNumber
    }, {
        Code: newCode,
        Number: newNumber
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The query is fine. Check if type of the values match. It returns both documents:

```
    {searchCode: 123, searchNumber:987, date: '2018-03-20'},
    {Code: 123, 'Number':987, date: '2018-03-20'}
```

But doesn't return

```
    {searchCode: '123', searchNumber:987, date: '2018-03-20'}
```

nor

```
    {searchCode: 123, searchNumber:987, date: ISODate('2018-03-20')}
```